# How do I Insert missing data into a bid data (94 million records) table

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, missing-data

Missing Seconds in Data:

[image: Missing Seconds in Data]

I have some big data 94 million records in a table called `[ESdata-1sec]`.  The data represents the date and time of S&P 500 eMini futures: `open`, `high`, `low`, `close` and `volume` values.

I want to insert into the data, the missing seconds.

For example the top record is at `00:05:23`, the next record in the table is for `00:05:33` (10 seconds later).  So the `[ESdata-1sec]` is missing entries for 9 seconds.

I want to insert records for `00:05::24, 00:05:25, 00:05:26 ... 00:05:32`.

I have a table (`DateRanges`) of `DateTime` entries that contains records for every second, so I could join/union to get the data for the date and time to insert, and the open high low close volume values will be the same as the last record (`00:05:23`).

I am at a loss as to how I could do this efficiently.  I could brute force loop through the `[ESdata-1sec]` table and add a record when a second was missing, but I'm not sure I would live long enough to see the result.

Any help in this area is appreciated.

Comment: recursive cte, outer join etc.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: please provide data and expected results as text in your question, [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). As per the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I am using MSSQL Server

Comment: Sounds like it would be easier, and less error-prone, to just reload ALL the data?

Comment: Hard code:  the original table did not have the missing seconds in the data.  So reloading would not fill in the gaps.  The answer from L_J was perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use Aggregate Window Function to create some group ID (`GID`) along with JOIN as it is shown below.

**Script to generate the inputs:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE #ESdata1sec
(
    [Date] DATE,
    [Time] TIME,
    [Open] FLOAT,
    [High] FLOAT,
    [Low] FLOAT,
    [Close] FLOAT,
    [Volume] INT
)

INSERT INTO #ESdata1sec VALUES
('2009-09-30', '00:05:23.000', 1056.25, 1056.25, 1056.25, 1056.25, 1),
('2009-09-30', '00:05:33.000', 1056.25, 1056.25, 1056.25, 1056.25, 1),
('2009-09-30', '00:05:51.000', 1056.25, 1056.25, 1056.25, 1056.25, 5),
('2009-09-30', '00:05:54.000', 1056.25, 1056.25, 1056.25, 1056.25, 4),
('2009-09-30', '00:05:55.000', 1056.25, 1056.25, 1056.25, 1056.25, 28),
('2009-09-30', '00:05:57.000', 1056.00, 1056.25, 1056.00, 1056.25, 15),
('2009-09-30', '00:06:07.000', 1056.25, 1056.25, 1056.25, 1056.25, 55),
('2009-09-30', '00:06:14.000', 1056.25, 1056.25, 1056.25, 1056.25, 10),
('2009-09-30', '00:06:19.000', 1056.25, 1056.25, 1056.25, 1056.25, 8)
GO

CREATE TABLE #DateRanges
(
    [Date] DATETIME
)

DECLARE @start AS DATETIME = '2009-09-30 00:05:23.000',
        @end   AS DATETIME = '2009-09-30 00:06:19.000'

WHILE @start <= @end
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #DateRanges VALUES (@start)
    SET @start = DATEADD(SECOND, 1, @start)
END
GO
```

**Solution:**

```sql
WITH x AS
(
    SELECT 
             SUM(CASE WHEN ID IS NOT NULL Then 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS GID
            ,[ID]
            ,[Date]
            ,[Open], [High], [Low], [Close], [Volume]
    FROM #DateRanges d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date], [Time]) AS ID
            ,CAST([Date] AS DATETIME) + CAST([Time] AS DATETIME) AS [FullDate]
            ,[Open], [High], [Low], [Close], [Volume]
        FROM #ESdata1sec
    ) e
    ON e.FullDate = d.Date
)
SELECT 
     a.[Date]
    ,b.[Open], b.[High], b.[Low], b.[Close], b.[Volume]
FROM x a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT  ID
            ,[Open], [High], [Low], [Close], [Volume]
    FROM x
    WHERE
        ID IS NOT NULL
) b
ON a.GID = b.ID
ORDER BY 
    a.[DATE]
```

**Output:**

```
+-------------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------+
|            Date         |  Open   |   High  |   Low   |   Close | Volume |
+-------------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------+
| 2009-09-30 00:05:23.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:24.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:25.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:26.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:27.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:28.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:29.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:30.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:31.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:32.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:33.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:34.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:35.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:36.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:37.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:38.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:39.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:40.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:41.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:42.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:43.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:44.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:45.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:46.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:47.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:48.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:49.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:50.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:51.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 5      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:52.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 5      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:53.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 5      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:54.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 4      |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:55.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 28     |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:56.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 28     |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:57.000 | 1056    | 1056.25 | 1056    | 1056.25 | 15     |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:58.000 | 1056    | 1056.25 | 1056    | 1056.25 | 15     |
| 2009-09-30 00:05:59.000 | 1056    | 1056.25 | 1056    | 1056.25 | 15     |
| 2009-09-30 00:06:00.000 | 1056    | 1056.25 | 1056    | 1056.25 | 15     |
| 2009-09-30 00:06:01.000 | 1056    | 1056.25 | 1056    | 1056.25 | 15     |
| 2009-09-30 00:06:02.000 | 1056    | 1056.25 | 1056    | 1056.25 | 15     |
| 2009-09-30 00:06:03.000 | 1056    | 1056.25 | 1056    | 1056.25 | 15     |
| 2009-09-30 00:06:04.000 | 1056    | 1056.25 | 1056    | 1056.25 | 15     |
| 2009-09-30 00:06:05.000 | 1056    | 1056.25 | 1056    | 1056.25 | 15     |
| 2009-09-30 00:06:06.000 | 1056    | 1056.25 | 1056    | 1056.25 | 15     |
| 2009-09-30 00:06:07.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 55     |
| 2009-09-30 00:06:08.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 55     |
| 2009-09-30 00:06:09.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 55     |
| 2009-09-30 00:06:10.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 55     |
| 2009-09-30 00:06:11.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 55     |
| 2009-09-30 00:06:12.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 55     |
| 2009-09-30 00:06:13.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 55     |
| 2009-09-30 00:06:14.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 10     |
| 2009-09-30 00:06:15.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 10     |
| 2009-09-30 00:06:16.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 10     |
| 2009-09-30 00:06:17.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 10     |
| 2009-09-30 00:06:18.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 10     |
| 2009-09-30 00:06:19.000 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 1056.25 | 8      |
+-------------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: Wow, that is exactly what I was looking for.  Very good explanation.  I have even learned something :-)  Thanks

Comment: You are welcome.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers